# Convert time to seconds and then convert it back to hours (JAVA)

Tags: java, time

I've been working on assignment for my homework and I'm stuck again. It's very simple task. (I think so)

For example I have 2493 seconds. 
I want to convert it to this format 00:41:33
I know I could use java.utilities but simple maths could solve it too(?)

```
if(Time>3600) { 
            Hours = Time/3600;
        }
        if(Time<3600)
        {
            Hours = 0;
        }

        Minutes = ((Time-(3600*Hours))/60);

        Seconds = ??????????;
```

So the only thing I don't get how do I get to know how many seconds left from this thing?

Comment: The only value i managed to get was  : 41.55.

Comment: By the way I'm using byte data type to store the data. Should I convert it to float, count it then and convert it back to byte?

Comment: `Seconds = (Time - (3600*Hours) - (60*Minutes));`

Comment: Hm. The output should look like 
`00:41:33` and I will use ` java.text.DecimalFormat; `for this thing. 
But the only value I manage to get is  `00:41:00`

Comment: Think you're looking for the modulus (`%`) operator to find the remainder after division. Another thing is the calculation of your minutes -- You don't need to use `Hours` here, you can just use `Time` to calculate this.

Comment: @brso05 Time is already in seconds. There's no need to use `Hours` or `Minutes` to calculate this.

Comment: I forgot that I can use `Time` for this and I was looking for complicated math in this task .... So stupid of me. Thanks @brso05 and @Saviour Self. 
But why should I use `while` Wouldn't `if`store the date just okay ?

Comment: @SaviourSelf yes there are other ways to do the calculation but maybe he has a reason for doing it this way. I just showed him how he can calculate seconds...

Comment: @RoccoMikal I removed my `while` comment as it was incorrect. I misread your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Time` is given in seconds, you can do the following for your calculation:

```
int hours = Time / 3600;
int minutes = (Time % 3600) / 60;
int seconds = Time % 60;
```

The modulus operator gives the remainder after division, and can be used to calculate minutes and seconds.

To calculate minutes, we want to remove all time over 1 hour, so we mod `Time` by 3600, then we divide by 60.

To calculate seconds, because `Time` is already in seconds, we mod `Time` by 60.

Comment: I have never used modulus so I didn't really knew what it is. I will go to wiki pedia and find out what it is exactly.

Comment: @RoccoMikal One other topic you may wish to look up is Integer Division in Java. Here's a quick reference [Math Operators in Java](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm)

Comment: Yeah I will check it. I'm trying to learn java as much as I can but my low math skills really doesn't help. Is math very important part of java in advanced java coding?

Comment: @RoccoMikal Math is important in any field, not just programming. Here, one important thing to take is that an `integer` is considered a whole number. When you divide an integer by an integer, you should expect an integer in return. Eg: `8 / 5 = 1`, because 5 goes in 8 once. The remainder however is `8 % 5 = 3` because 5 goes into 8 once, but has a remainder of 3.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the general formula for convertions like this.  You do have to remember to subtract the values you have previously converted.  For example, after you calculate the hours, you have to subtract the hours so you can then convert the minutes.

```
public class TimeConverstion
{

   private static void convert( int i )
   {
      int hours = i / 3600;
      i = i - hours * 3600;
      int minutes = i / 60;
      i = i - minutes * 60;
      int seconds = i;
      System.out.printf( "Hours:%d, minutes:%d, seconds%d%n", hours, minutes, 
              seconds );
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      convert( 149580 );
   }
}
```

Output of this program:

```
run:
Hours:41, minutes:33, seconds0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```